# Unable to Load XML file which is dynamically created. And Xml without encoding tag how do i add root encoding tag after creating XML file

Tags: c#, xml

```
if (!File.Exists(locationFile))
{
    string file = @"mypathtoxml";
    XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(file); //- i get error here in loading my XML file which is created dynamically. 
    //process cannot access my path(my xml file Location) because it is being used by another process
}
```

Comment: Somebody please help . Thanks in advance for help

Comment: You have two different questions from the look of it, so you should ask two different questions. As for the "being used by another process" error - how are you creating the file? Are you closing it properly? How do you know when it has finished being created?

Comment: Both of your questions relate to the *creation* of the xml rather than the reading of it - you should show that code.

Comment: Problem solved  File.Create(folderPath + "/" + newXml).Close(); after creating file need to close file. <?xml version="1.0"?> add tag and  then i can save data to it.

Comment: Yes Matthew watson i have two query's. I was creating a file but didnt close it so that was my bug . Because dynamically/Manually when we create a file in Visual studio it opens a file. So to perform operation i need to close it properly. And go ahead with my functionality of saving or loading XML file. It solved my error : File.Create(folderPath + "/" + newXml).Close();

Answer (score 0):

You could wait a while and try it again. For example something like this:

```
var finished = false;
while (!finished)
{
  try
  {
    if (!File.Exists(locationFile))
    {
      string file = @"mypathtoxml";
      XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.Load(file); 
      finished = true;
    }
  }
  catch (IOException)
  {
    // the file is unavailable because it is:
    // - still being written to
    // - being processed by another thread
    // so we just wait a second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

In order to terminate sometime, you could add a counter and only try it 10 times or so.

Comment: On creation of XML (dynamically) without encoding tag. Its first duty to add <?xml version=\"1.0\"?> tag and then save it file. Finally Load XML to perform operations. Because while loading file ( doc.Load(file);  )which isnt sure which type it is actually was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string file = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><mypathtoxml>" + File.ReadAllText(FILENAME) +  "</mypathtoxml>";
            XmlDocument objXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            objXmlDoc.LoadXml(file); ​​
```

Comment: You've changed the file path to some fixed xml string.  How does that help read the file that's in use?

Comment: I modified the code to add xml definition and root tag to existing file.